# What do people eat after the nuclear attack in the Terminator movies?

Tags: the-terminator

The survivors of judgement day, what do they eat to survive?

There is a scene with a old lady eating something in a bowl, looks like porridge?

Comment: Cockroach stew, I expect. Or Tastee Wheat

Comment: In the novels you see them eating food scavenged from stores, some fresh food grown hydroponically and lots and lots of MREs and food bars.

Comment: A kid was showing a rat he caught, sooo... I don't think they would let it go to waste.